# Page not submitting with large volume of items in the listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have my web page with more than 4000 of list items in the listbox. When I submit the page nothing is happening and the browser is just spinning forever. Where as the same listbox is working good with small number of items. And this is happening only on specific server (Production server only). What could be the issue?

Comment: open the `network` panel and see what's going on.

Comment: On PHP servers there is limit in `max_input_vars=1000`, so maybe you have something similar for your ASP server

Comment: Maybe this can solve the problem: https://webconnection.west-wind.com/docs/_4lp0zgm9d.htm

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am actually modifying the data on the listbox using the javascript. Also It is working with larger amount of data too for some cases. Would it be a data issue?